# background no-repeat sets the background-clip property to padding-box?

Tags: css, background

We have simple list with three list items. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5301soq8/1/).

First li background property set to:

```
background: url(http://url-here.png) no-repeat 0 50% / 15px 15px;
```

no-repeat is set, but background-clip is omitted.

Second li has background where both no-repeat and border-box set:

```
background: url(http://url-here.png) no-repeat 0 50% / 15px 15px border-box;
```

and third li similar to first li, but background-clip set manually:

```
background: url(http://url-here.png) no-repeat 0 50% / 15px 15px;
background-clip: border-box;
```

Keeping in mind that default value for background-clip is "border-box", I assume that setting the value for second and third li is redundant, but only second li display the background image as it should.

[image]

Tested in Opera v. 37.0.2178.54 and Google Chrome v. 50.0.2661.102 m

Please help me to figure out the way it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the `background-repeat` does not affect the `background-clip` property in any way. The difference that you are seeing in the second `li` is due to a different reason. In the short-hand property when we provide only one `box` value, both `background-clip` and `background-origin` get the same value.

From the [W3C Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background):

> If one  value is present then it sets both ‘background-origin’ and ‘background-clip’ to that value.

So, your second `li` gets `background-origin: border-box` whereas for the other two it gets set with the [default value which is `padding-box`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#the-background-origin).

`background-origin` is the property that specifies from where the `background` should start. Since the first and third `li` get the `background-origin` set as `padding-box`, their background is set within the padding box area (inside the border).

If same `background-origin` is set for all three `li` then they will display the same way irrespective of the `background-repeat` setting.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.no-repeat {
  background: url(http://postcrossing-ua.com/static/pybb/smiles/D83DDE03.png) no-repeat 0 50% / 15px 15px;
  background-origin: border-box;
}
.no-repeat-border-box {
  background: url(http://postcrossing-ua.com/static/pybb/smiles/D83DDE03.png) no-repeat 0 50% / 15px 15px border-box;
}
.border-box {
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="no-repeat">White</li>
  <li class="no-repeat-border-box">Black</li>
  <li class="no-repeat border-box">Red</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Harry, it makes sense!